# How to Crop a Frame With Jquery no Canvas

Tags: html, jquery, crop, sprite-sheet

I need to make a knight for chess(a new project I'm working on). I have a sprite sheet of all the pieces, but I am stuggling to use just one. I need a single piece in a 130px by 130px square. I chose a knight because why not(doesnt have to be in examples). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OXx4.png) is the sprite sheet I'm using. I tried a jQuery script appending a new image, then I tried to resize and stuff, no luck. Then I made a `<div>` and resized that, but I cannot make the background image the chess sprite with jQuery. That code is:

```
$('.pieces > .white').append('<div class="white wKnight wK' + wK + '" style="width: 130px; height: 130px"></div>');
$('.wK' + wK).css('background-image', ChessSprites.png)
```

Html:

```
<div class="pieces">
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

`wK` stands for `whiteKnight` and it starts at one and counts up for each knight made, so each is callable individually. I am aware there are probably better ways than that, but I am still learning, and that is what I understand. I do not want to use canvas, as that will be very excessive and difficult imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the background of an element to a arbitrary piece of an image you can use the `background-position` css style.

```js
$('.pieces > .white').append('<div class="white wKnight wK" style="width: 130px; height: 130px"></div>');
$('.wK').css({'background-image': 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OXx4.png)', 'background-position': '390px 0px'});
$('.pieces > .black').append('<div class="black bKnight bK" style="width: 130px; height: 130px"></div>');
$('.bK').css({'background-image': 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OXx4.png)', 'background-position': '390px 130px'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pieces">
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works, but is there a way to use my downloaded file called `ChessSprites.png`?

Comment: Hello? I've tried looking it up. I can't find anything on how to use downloaded files, only how to download files for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by `downloaded` file?

Comment: I have a downloaded file, and I want to use that instead of the online one. How do I do that? I tried looking it up, but for some reason the search results always say howbto download files, not how to use them.

Comment: That would require user intervention. Have a file input for the user to select the file. Get the `File` from the input and create a blob url and use that as the background image